# Hide lines based on multiple patterns

Tags: logs, less, filter

I'm using `less` to view log files quite a lot and every so often I'd like to filter the output by hiding lines which contains *some keywords*.

In `less` it's possible to filter-out lines with `&!<keyword>` but that only works for one keyword at a time.
I'd like to specify a list of keywords to filter-out. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
 &!cat|dog|fish
```